# Powershell -cant get my script to Filter out Departments From Organisation Info

Tags: powershell

PowerShell -cant get my script to Filter out Departments

Hello everyone, like in the Title I cant get my script to install Printers Based on the "Department" Organization info given in the AD. I'm learning a bit PowerShell since a week but I am a complete Noob and have no clue what is wrong with my Script

```
$AllUsers = Get-ADUser -filter * -properties Department
ForEach ($User in $AllUsers)
{
$UserDep = $User.Department

IF ($UserDep -eq "Information Technology")

{

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA C4050iSeriesPCL"
Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA C360iSeriesPCL"  
Add-Printer -connectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH18                                 
Add-Printer -connectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH16
}



IF ($UserDep -eq "Supply Chain & Logistics")

{

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA 5000i PCL"
Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA C360iSeriesPCL"
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH21                      
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH05
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH33
}



IF ($UserDep -eq "Customer Support")

{
Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA C360iSeriesPCL"
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH10
}
}
```

It just adds all the Printers anyway without actually filtering anything

Comment: This seems fairly expensive for a login script.  A user may be in multiple departments, but it seems like it would still work to me.

Comment: Hey, yes it is kind of long but i got no clue how to write it otherwise and it works with installing all the printers yes but it doesn't really filter it by the department. I don't want all the printers being installed just the ones acc sitting in the department :/

Comment: Use following to help debug problem.  You are missing Department.  It may be a different property.  So use for debugging  1)$AllUsers | Format-Table  2) or inside the For loop $User |  Format-Table

Comment: You can do `get-aduser $env:username`.  The script won't delete any extra printers for a user that are already there.

Comment: Hey guys , sry just got back now, thx for all the suggestions, i will try them out now 

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments, [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010)'s comment specifically made me realize what you're doing. If this is a logon script, this is in fact a *very* expensive computation. This is supposed to be user based but what you're doing is querying all users and comparing them to see what department they belong in, then adding the corresponding printer/driver to the computer. That's why you have all of them added.

When using the query to AD with `Get-ADUser -filter * -properties Department`, you are looping through each user returned and comparing their department. The user you should query is the logged in user and not everyone:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:USERNAME -Properties 'Department'
switch ($user.Department)
{
    'Information Technology' { 
        Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA C4050iSeriesPCL"
        Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA C360iSeriesPCL"  
        Add-Printer -connectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH18                                 
        Add-Printer -connectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH16
    }
    'Supply Chain & Logistics' { 
        Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA 5000i PCL"
        Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA C360iSeriesPCL"
        Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH21                      
        Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH05
        Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH33
    }
    'Customer Support' {
        Add-PrinterDriver -Name "KONICA MINOLTA C360iSeriesPCL"
        Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\LMSMAN-Print01\MH10
    }
}
```

Comment: Note if Department is an array, switch will loop though each one.

Comment: @js2010, *if*, fortunately, it's a single-valued attribute.

Comment: Ahh your a star, this works like a charm. thx you so much i think i understand now what the Problem was as well